# Why can I not assign values to a shared pointer array?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

This small example is giving the error message

```
Error   C2440   '=': cannot convert from '_Ux (*const )' to 'int *' Templ   1266
Error   C3692   non-scalar type 'int []' cannot be used in a pseudo-destructor expression
```

What is `_Ux(*const)`?

This is the program:

```
#include <memory>
int main()
{
    shared_ptr<int[]> as = make_shared<int[]>(10);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        as[i] = i + 100;
    }
}
```

Comment: Apologies, the `std` namespaces is used.

Comment: It's likely the c++20 support that @RemyLebeau also mentioned in his answer

Comment: I use Visual Studio C++ 2019, with lanugage Standard C++17. When switching from `shared_ptr` to `unique_ptr` the code runs as shown.

Answer (score 3):

The code as shown does not compile, because `shared_ptr` and `make_shared()` are in the `std` namespace, but there is no `using namespace std;` statement, or at least `using std::shared_ptr;` and `using std::make_shared;` statements.

However, fixing that, make sure you are compiling this code for C++20, as `std::make_shared()` does not support the creation of arrays in earlier versions, which can lead to the error you are seeing.

In C++17, you will have to construct the array manually instead, but `std::shared_ptr` will free the array correctly, eg:

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<int[]> as( new int[10] );
```

[Live Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/Zp3C-Rbsj)

But, `std::shared_ptr` does not support arrays at all in C++11 and C++14, so you will have to use a custom deleter to free the array properly, and use `std::shared_ptr::get()` instead of `std::shared_ptr::operator[]` to access the array elements, eg:

```cpp
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> as( new int[10], [](int *p) { delete[] p; } );
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        as.get()[i] = i + 100;
    }
}
```

For dynamic arrays, you should consider using `std::vector` instead, eg:

```cpp
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> as(10);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        as[i] = i + 100;
    }
}
```